# Is it possible to capture the data with PROCESS BUILDER while deleting a record?

Tags: process-builder

I have X & Y objects, on deleting record of X object i need to create record on Y object with deleted record data.
**NOTE** : USING PROCESS BUILDER.

Comment: Not without a trigger

Comment: Procees builder only fire create or update of any record. not on delete

Answer (score 1):

As of the Winter 16 release, you can only run a process when a record is either:

A) Created

B) Created or Edited

To do what you're describing though could be done quite easily with an apex trigger.

[image: process builder screenshot]